# How to titleize words in text_area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, title

How to titleize/captialize words (with the exception of some prepositions) in the text_area as the user types in their words in real time?

```
<%= f.text_area :name %>
```

For example, to create the same behavior as this website: http://titlecapitalization.com/

Comment: What have you tried? According to Google there are about 150 prepositions in the English language. Have you made a list of the ones you don't want capitalized?

Comment: I could just add more prepositions as I go, but to start "on, but, of" is good enough. Yes I did a lot of google, but I couldn't find anything that solves for my question @Jordan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Jquery, your problem will be solved by code given below.

```
function makeTitle(slug) {
    var words = slug.split(' ');

    $.each(words, function(index, word){
        words[index] = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
    });

    return words.join(' ');
}

$(element_selector).on('keyup', function(){ $(this).val( makeTitle($(this).val())) })
```

Comment: Hey sir you know how I can include exceptions for a few prepositions like, "on, but, of, etc"?

Comment: We can do this, to achieve this we have to check complete word, in this case, we can't titleize word until we get complete world(or press a space).
Or we have to downcase the string. after get complete word which is exceptional.